# How to show a Google Map in Android-Mobile

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

`enter code here` I have created a project that shows Google maps in android emulator
..But still it doesn't display map in my emulator.I am using Google API key.

I have used my SHAFingerprint to create a Google API key and included that in my Manifest.

I also referred Google-play-services-lib library and also the jar file.

When i searched on Internet some has said that only maps is viewable in mobile phone,in android emulator it wont be displayed.

Here is my code if i has made any mistakes please let me know.. or if there any new way to display maps in emulator or andorid mobiles please give me the way how to do that.

Here is my code in MainActivity

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       //Add a marker
        mMap = ((MapFragment)        getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

}
```

}

Here is my code in the XML file

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is my Android Manifest Code...

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapviewv2example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapviewv2example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapviewv2example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <meta-data
        android:name="--------------------------------//some values"

        android:value="-------------------------------//Google  API KEY value" />

</application>
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem......Eagerly Awaiting for Responses...

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: AFAIK, the Android emulator still does not support Maps V2.

Comment: change minsdk from 11 to 12

Comment: @CommonsWare: From Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services. So the Maps V2 can work on emulator from 4.2.2 version & above

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, referencing the Google Android Map Api v2 you can't run google maps v2 on Android emulator; you must use a device for your tests.

Comment: Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.